# AWS IoT reboot Job never executes - Forever queued

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I might be confused about how this is supposed to work, but I setup a device as a Greengrass Core v2 device and created a `reboot` job from the managed `AWS-Reboot` template and it never executes on the device.

The goal of this is just a proof of concept before I delve much deeper creating my own jobs like pulling new versions of our software.

Details:

```
Job type is "Snapshot". 
Device is running Ubuntu 18.04
Java: OpenJDK 16.0.2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into my post.

Greengrass doesn't support Managed Templates for IoT Jobs. They're for AWS IoT Device Client: https://repost.aws/questions/QUMwi9PxDcRT6xu1jEQEfj8g